# Google sheet auto populate row script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image: Example here]I am using a google sheet in which a new row is added by inserting Col A thru a third party app. Once Col A is added I wish to copy the formula from the remaining row cells above to auto calculate the values using the formulas in that row.
ArrayFormula doesn't help as I don't want to have the rows created in advance before Col A is populated.
Any script which can do this?

Comment: Hi, consider providing a copy of your spreadsheet to visually clarify what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Updated a screenshot for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with the onChange event.  Go ahead and test to see that you get the onChange event when you update columnA with the third party app.

Comment: Apps Script triggers can only detect manual changes, not programmatic ones. Therefore, I don't think this is possible via script. About `ArrayFormula doesn't help as I don't want to have the rows created in advance before Col A is populated`, what do you mean by `rows created in advance`? The formula could keep those cells blank and populate them when column A is populated.

Comment: The 3rd party app adds new rows below the existing ones. So in case a blank cell already exists with a formula, it will add the new entry on the next new row which is totally blank. So the problem isn't solved.

Comment: If your issue with an array formula is that it will display #NA errors or other values prior to a new entry, this can easily be fixed with some filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for *can* be achieved with a formula. I have created a quick sheet to demonstrate this.

[image]

Cell `B1` contains the following formula:

```
={"Formula";ifna(arrayformula(filter(A2:A, A2:A<>"")*5))}
```

This formula defines the header (meaning that it is placed in the first row, ultimately not affecting any third party data inputs), and then uses an array formula for the rest of the column. This formula works because of the filter. That filters out any cells that are not blank and multiplies them by 5. The `IFNA` portion ensures that if there is no data at all, the second row is still left completely blank. This was verified with a script I wrote to simulate a data entry.

```js
function test() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().appendRow([Math.random()]);
}
```

This script is simple, and uses the `appendRow()` method to simulate what a third party entry would do. I used this script, and the result is displayed in the screenshot above. This shows that an appended row will still populate the next blank row, despite there being an array formula in cell `B1`. Using this logic, it is possible to change the formula to populate the actual data that you need.

Comment: Thank you for taking the pain. This seems to have done the trick. Thanks again.